# Jquery not work after content is loaded with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

This JQuery script work well when normally web page open.

But with in the result of AJAX, this jquery function not work.

```
<script>
$(".box").each(function(){
  var value = parseInt($(this).data("value"));
if (value == 1)
   var color = "red";
else if (value == 2 || value == 3)
  var color = "yellow";
else
  var color = "green";
for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
$(this).after("<div class='newBox' style='background:"+color+"'></div>");
});
</script>
```

**How to make this script workable with in AJAX result as well?**

This is AJAX Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#test .br').click(function() {
 var choices = {};
 console.log(choices);
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'call_post',
        'choices': choices,
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('.filter-output').append(result);
    }
 });
})
});
```

**Please check here**  [Server Link](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/tablet/)

Comment: *jquery function not work* what does not work what do you expect what is happening

Comment: @guradio in Ajax result this not show color box.. but normally web page this work

Comment: put the code inside document ready as well

Comment: Do not use `success` handler, use jQuery deferred `.done`.

Comment: $(".box").each(function(){ }); will run on page load . so it will not load on ajax success so need to run it again after ajax success or you can make it as function and call every time of ajax success .

Comment: I update my question with [server link](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/tablet/) to check problem

Comment: try my answer @FRQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in comment `$(".box").each(function(){ });` will run on page load only . so it will not run on after ajax success . so need to run that again after ajax success or you can make it as function and call every time of ajax success . like this

```
        <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function color()
    {
        $(".box").each(function(){
          var value = parseInt($(this).data("value"));
        if (value == 1)
           var color = "red";
        else if (value == 2 || value == 3)
          var color = "yellow";
        else
          var color = "green";
        for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
        $(this).after("<div class='newBox' style='background:"+color+"'></div>");
        });
    }

    color(); //called on page load


    //ajax 


        $('#test .br').click(function() {
                var choices = {};
                console.log(choices);
                $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'action': 'call_post',
                        'choices': choices,
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('.filter-output').append(result);
                        color(); //call the function again here 
                        ^^^^^^^
                    }
                 });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Now this work only for Ajax,not for simple page load. Please check [server link](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/tablet/)

Comment: you need to call this function two time  1) on page load color(); //called on page load  2) after ajax success .

Comment: did noted that on end of function i called the function like this function color(){ ... } //function declaring   color(); //function calling @FRQ

Comment: glad to help you @FRQ

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are altering each `.box` items when the page is load, and need to modify again when ajax has a result.

if then, you can make it as a function and call it in the `success` part of your ajax and in your `$(document).ready`.

```
function alterBox(){
        $(".box").each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).data("value"));
        if (value == 1)
           var color = "red";
        else if (value == 2 || value == 3)
          var color = "yellow";
        else
            var color = "green";

        for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
            $(this).after("<div class='newBox' style='background:"+color+"'></div>");
    });
}
```

success part in your ajax code:

```
 success: function(result) {
   $('.filter-output').append(result);
   alterBox();
}
```

Comment: Now this work only for Ajax,not for simple page load. Please check [server link](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/tablet/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change -> click to on click. $('#test .br').click(function() {

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).on('click', '#test .br', function() {
 var choices = {};
 console.log(choices);
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'call_post',
        'choices': choices,
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('.filter-output').append(result);
    }
 });
})
});
```